# COALESCE with IN condition in sql server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

COALESCE is used to use next not null value in condition. For example
**@DOCTOR_NUM** is variable that can be ***NULL or contains DOCTOR NUMBER***
for that we can user query like

```
DOCTOR_NUM = COALESCE(@DOCTOR_NUM,DOCTOR_NUM)
```

So we no need to generate the dynamic query for optional condition.

My Question is that can we use coalesce for IN condition.
Like `@DOCTOR_NUM='123,234,345'`

```
DCOTOR_NUM IN COALESCE(REPLACE(@DOCTOR_NUM,',',''','''),DOCTOR_NUM)
```

Comment: A single string containing commas (and, after you replace, quote marks too) is *not* the same as *multiple* values. There are various ways of transforming a single string containing multiple "values" truly into multiple values, but your attempt here isn't one of them. And really, the best cure is to switch to using a data type *designed* to hold multiple values (e.g. a table-valued parameter, xml, json, etc)

Comment: as @Damien_The_Unbeliever said, you have an XY problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to avoid using functions or tampering with values when doing multiple optional filters (or better yet, use Dynamic SQL).

You can't use a simple variable to hold multiple values, you need a table (variable or not) for that.

A solution would be something with the following guidelines:

```
DECLARE @DOCTOR_NUM VARCHAR(1000) = '123,234,345'


DECLARE @t_SuppliedDoctorNumbers TABLE (DoctorNumber INT)

INSERT INTO @t_SuppliedDoctorNumbers (
    DoctorNumber)
SELECT
    DoctorNumber = S.Value
FROM
    STRING_SPLIT(@DOCTOR_NUM, ',') AS S -- SQL Server 2016+ can use String_Split, many other options for lower versions
WHERE
    TRY_PARSE(S.Value AS INT) IS NOT NULL


SELECT
    *
FROM
    YourTable AS T
WHERE
    (@DOCTOR_NUM IS NULL OR 
        EXISTS (SELECT 'valid doctor number' FROM @t_SuppliedDoctorNumbers AS X WHERE X.DoctorNumber = T.DOCTOR_NUM))
```